# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos x}{\cos x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definition

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos x}{\cos x}$$

I think that $\cos x$ does not exist if $x\to\infty$. But $\dfrac{\cos x }{\cos x}$. I am confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Limit of a constant function $f(x)=c$ is just $c$. $\frac{cos(x)}{cos(x)}$ is $1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee How is $\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}$ constant? What is its value at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: $\infty$ is an *accumulation point* of the domain of the function $\frac{\cos}{\cos}$, meaning that according to the more general definition of the limit, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}=1$.

Answer (score 3):

That fraction has the value $1$ except where $\cos$ has a root. At those places it's undefined, though it would be reasonable to define it as $1$. Whether the limit exists depends on what you want to do at those points. If the limit does exist it will be $1$ since it's the limit of a constant function.

In any case trying to evaluate it as the quotient of the limit of $\cos$ makes no sense (as you note in the question).